# Sdl2-config not found error( installing pygame_sdl2)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to install pygame_sdl2. When I write:
python setup.py install 
I get error:
sh:1:sdl2-config not found

subprocess.CalledProcessError: command'['sh','-c','sdl-config' --cflags']' returned non-zero exit status 127
I don't know what to do.
I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the SDL2 package. Try this:

```
wget http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.9.tar.gz
```

to download SDL2. Then run:

```
tar -xzvf SDL2-2.0.9.tar.gz
cd SDL2-2.0.9
./configure 
sudo make all
```

Comment: I tried this just now but when I run python setup.py install I get same error :-(

Comment: Where exactly do I have to install the sdl2 package? @TzurEl

Comment: How are you installing your pygame_dsl2?

Comment: Downloaded the pygame_sdl2 compressed file from GitHub https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2?files=1    and after installing windeps I am trying to run python setup.py install (the procedure for windows)

Comment: Actually I am on Ubuntu but.   sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev virtualenvwrapper.  This gives error  some packages not installed try apt-get update or --fix missing

Comment: Wait, you need to install it on virtualenv. Deploy a virtualenv and then install everything. It should work.

Comment: (Thanks for the answers)but I did n't get how to do it.Could you please explain

Comment: run 'pip install virtualenv', after that run 'virtualenv <env_name>'. Last step is to do 'source <env_name>/bin/activate', and then try to install everything. It should work.

Comment: I don't know why it gives the same error!